# Execute immediate run from a PL/SQL package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have the following lines of code in a PL/SQL package

```
l_sql := 'alter table LOG_FILES location ('||chr(39)|| filename || to_char(sysdate,'DDMMYY') ||chr(39)||'))';
execute immediate l_sql;
```

The pl/sql package compiles fine but i dont see the change. The alter command has no effect at all. Is there any reason for this?

Note: The table I am trying to alter is an [Oracle External table.](http://orafaq.com/node/848)

Comment: You say the package compiles fine.  Did you run the procedure in the package that actually executes the dynamic SQL?

Comment: Yes i did. The problem was with the extra closing bracket and the escaped single quotes - Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filename is a string and needs to be bracketed with single quotes in the final statement.  In order to acheive that you need to escape the single quote.   One way is to use two single quotes.  So, your assignment needs to look something like this:

```
l_sql := 'alter table LOG_FILES location ('''|| filename || to_char(sysdate,'DDMMYY') ||''')';
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra parentheses at the end of your statement